# Chart.js - rendering a time graph with 'day' as a unit on x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js (2.7). I have my dates in the labels array in ISO format, I have also tried to save them in millisecond ticks. And my dataset's data are random positive integers.

My graph's config looks like this:

```
 {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [] as any[],
        labels: [] as string[]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            }
        },

        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Pinged At (Date and Time)'
                },
                type: "time",
                
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Response Time (ms)'
                }
                
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This does not render anything! It does detect the what the labels would be:

[image]

But no datapoints. However, when I set the unit to hours, and then display the data, it works fine.

My labels array contains datapoints like this:
["2022-06-30T16:24:07.713+05:00", "2022-07-07T15:23:02.742+05:00"]

And my datapoints are like this:
[1,11]

Can anyone tell me if I have made any mistake with its configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing your datasets you need to call the myChart.update() afterwards. When I get no datapoints, that is my first thought.

Comment: I am not pushing new datapoints. I have a pre-defined array of datapoints.